# Cannot get foreach to properly generate html table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, foreach

I have the following 2 tables:

```
         --  members --

      |member_ID|nick_name|
      ---------------------
      |    1    |   Jack  |
      ---------------------
      |    2    |   Jill  |
      ---------------------

           -- shares --

|member_ID|nick_name|percent_owner|
-----------------------------------
|   1     |  Jack   |     75      |
-----------------------------------
|   2     |  Jill   |     25      |
-----------------------------------
```

My first php page will query the members table and create an html table just fine. In the html table, I added a blank text box to manually enter the percent owner value. This is what that table looks like:

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($members as $members) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $members['member_ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $members['nick_name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="percent_owner[]" value="" size="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Now, what I am trying to do is send the new information to another page to create another html table with the member_ID, nick_name, and percent owner. This where my problem lies. Here is the 2nd html table:

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($members as $member) : ?>
  <?php foreach ($_POST['percent_owner'] as $value) : ?>                
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $member['member_ID']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $member['nick_name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>                 
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I don't believe I am organizing my foreach statements properly. Either I get only the first percent_owner value in every row, or I get both in each row, but cannot get it right. Once I have this figured out, I will then enter it all into the shares table but that will come later. I need to tackle this first.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to match the data entered to the row it is applied. One way to do it is to add a hidden value to each row with the member id parallel to the percent owner. Theoretically they will both end up with the same index in their respective arrays and you just need to match that up. But that is an ugly and unreliable way to do it.

Another way you can handle this (definitely the better of the two ways) is to set the name of the user input field for percent owner to be percent_owner_[member id] when your building the form field in the table. Then when you submit the form you can just iterate through the POST variables looking for the sub-string of "percent_owner_" and when you identify those inputs you extract the member id and the user-entered value and save it to an indexed array. Then you use the extracted id to query the DB for other member information.

Example form fields:

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($members as $members) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $members['member_ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $members['nick_name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="percent_owner_<?=$members['member_ID']?>" value="" size="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Then on submit you would process it like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST AS $input => $value) {
  if (stristr($input, 'percent_owner_')) {
    $memberID = str_replace('percent_owner_', '', $input);
    $res = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT nick_name FROM members WHERE member_ID = '$memberID'"));

    $data[$memberID] = array(
      'memberID' => $memberID,
      'nickName' => $res->nick_name,
      'percentOwner' => $value
    );
  }
}
?>

<table>
  <?php foreach ($data as $member) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $member['memberID']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member['nickName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $member['percentOwner']; ?></td>
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: First, thank you for your help. Why would I have to do a sql query to get the nick_name when it is already being posted from the first form? Aren't member_id, nick_name, and percent_owner already in the $_POST array?

Comment: No, not at all. Just because you output data to HTML doesn't mean it will send it back on a form post. Not without putting the data into a form input. It has no way of determining what was return data otherwise.

Comment: If you want the other items back you will need to encode their values into a form field. Possibly a hidden input field. But there is no need to do that at all because the data is in your database.

Comment: Have you messed around with any Content Management Systems (CMSes)? Check out Wordpress and Drupal. Both are free and could help you learn alot (especially Drupal).

Comment: but the way i have it right now, the table being built has the member_id, nick_name, and percent_owner. my only problem is that percent_owner is either being duplicated or showing up on multiple rows, etc. i feel like it's just a formatting issue i'm having.

Comment: The only way that $members var would still be populated is if you have code that is re-populating it. Are you submitting the form to the same page? If you are then that is what is going on. Your code is running again and loading it again. Only form values get sent back to the server by the browser.

Comment: I could review the full script for you. Just save it to pastbin and drop the link in here. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Yeah, so do you see where it says "$members = get_members_by_org($org_ID);"? That is re-populating the variable with that function call and the org ID. It isn't coming from the form submit at all. You could do a nested foreach to read that.

Comment: Ok, i am understanding now. so as I stated in my original post (above), I am trying to grab everything in that form and post that data into the shares table. i only threw it into this temp.php file for t-shooting purposes.

Comment: Just write the SQL insert and loop through the data. Obviously you need to add filtering and checking, but you can Google that easily enough. I really recommend checking out the CodeIgniter framework. Here is the modified code: http://pastebin.com/BfeDxvDx  Please remember to vote my answer up/accept it.

Comment: i am going to test this in about 2 hours. i will vote, don't worry

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a different variable for the iteration variable in the first block of code, one that's not the array.

```
foreach ($members as $member)
```

make it:

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($members as $member) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $member['member_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $member['nick_name']; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="percent_owner[]" value="" size="3"></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**Update:**

You're trying to loop through both % for each row, what you want is the % that is in that row.

```
<table>
  <?php
   $i = 0;
   $percents = expload(',', $_POST['percent_owner']);
   foreach ($members as $member) : ?>                
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $member['member_ID']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $member['nick_name']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $percents[$i++]; ?></td>                 
   </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And you'll probably want to change the name of the input in the first block to just "percent_owner". Also, take this code with a grain of salt, as it is untested.

Comment: but what about the next page? is my problem on the 2nd page because of this? like I said, the first table appears to be working just fine. it's the 2nd table where I'm having issues. I do see your point, however. I will fix that.